# Temporary Wi-Fi connection loss occurs

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, connection

I have a trouble with my laptop's wireless connection.
Config is as follows:

Network device:
EchoLife HG8245 GPON Terminal (CLASS B+), WLAN enabled, mode 802.11 b/g/n, WPA2\PSK - AES.

Laptop:
HP ProBook 650, Windows 10, domain-joined.
Connected to PON terminal above via Wi-Fi.
Network adapter Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter

Symptoms:
When working on a laptop connected to the Internet via Wi-Fi a temporary connection loss occurs with random intervals.
Wi-Fi icon in tray shows the yellow exclamation sign, on hover the title "No internet connection".
ipconfig /all is ok, IP address, gateway and DNS servers are assigned.
When trying to ping any host there is a 100% packet loss, when trying to traceroute  any host - there is a time out always.
Switching Wi-Fi off and on using hardware switch solves the problem.

Also sometimes the broken connection is repaired automatically by Windows - by reconnecting to Wi-Fi.

Google Chrome said "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET" and ping - "
PING: transmit failed. General failure."

When connected to the PON terminal via LAN cable (RJ45) no problem is present.

The PON terminal isn't overheated.
It works stable with any other devices (mobile phones, tablets and even another laptop (Dell Latitude)).

I need a solution how to diagnose this issue\ how to analyse the root cause.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully fixed by updating network card drivers via Device Manager to
v. 7.35.344.0 \ Broadcom BCM943228HMB 802.11abgn 2x2 Wi-Fi Adapter